# Add ons disappear on Layout workspace

Tags: add-on

This just happened recently. I've been using Blender 3.1.2 and for some reason any additional Add ons I have selected in my preferences disappear after a while in the Layout workspace. The only way I can access them is in my other workspaces for some reason? If anyone has a suggestion on what is happening or how I can fix this it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,
Craigers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.